# NSDateFormatter returns nil date with simple request

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I use the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *eventCreationDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventCreationDateString];
        NSLog(@"eventCreationDateString = %@; eventCreationDate = %@", eventCreationDateString, eventCreationDate);
```

NSLog result is: `eventCreationDateString = 2014-01-23 14:42:27; eventCreationDate = (null)`

It's really strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Your time is in 24hr format so use `HH` instead of `hh`

Answer (score 3):

Your format should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```